# How can I scrape an HTML table to CSV?

Tags: screen-scraping

## The Problem

I use a tool at work that lets me do queries and get back HTML tables of info. I do not have any kind of back-end access to it.

A lot of this info would be much more useful if I could put it into a spreadsheet for sorting, averaging, etc. **How can I screen-scrape this data to a CSV file?**

### My First Idea

Since I know jQuery, I thought I might use it to strip out the table formatting onscreen, insert commas and line breaks, and just copy the whole mess into notepad and save as a CSV. **Any better ideas?**

## The Solution

Yes, folks, it really was as easy as copying and pasting. Don't I feel silly.

Specifically, when I pasted into the spreadsheet, I had to select "Paste Special" and choose the format "text." Otherwise it tried to paste everything into a single cell, even if I highlighted the whole spreadsheet.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery idea because I wanted XML and mapping XML in Excel is huge pain in the ass (for ad hoc data sets).. turns out this is very easy to do for *any* website using JS console (dynamically inject jquery.js if not there, then use simple transformation from HTML table data into csv/xml/json/whatever using `$("tr", "#table tbody").each()`)

Comment: There's a [Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/html-table-scraper/ncphhmcjgbpglahiijnaaaaneoijlmkj). (if the table seems never ending while copying)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

- Select the HTML table in your tools's UI and copy it into the clipboard (if that's possible
- Paste it into Excel.
- Save as CSV file

However, this is a manual solution not an automated one.

Comment: This works with IE, but I don't believe it works with FF, even with Paste Special, I believe it just dumps everything into the first cell.

Comment: No, I did it with FF3. I selected all in the spreadsheet before doing the Paste Special > Text. Maybe it doesn't work if the underlying HTML is formatted a certain way?

Comment: I dont think this solution is scalable.
From the question, it seems Nathan wants to have a code like one given below.

Answer (score 13):

using python:

for example imagine you want to scrape forex quotes in csv form from some site like:[fxquotes](http://www.oanda.com/convert/fxhistory?date_fmt=us&date=11/10/08&date1=01/01/08&exch=USD&exch2=USD&expr=AUD&expr2=AUD&lang=en&margin_fixed=0&format=CSV&redirected=1)

then...

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib,string,csv,sys,os
from string import replace

date_s = '&date1=01/01/08'
date_f = '&date=11/10/08'
fx_url = 'http://www.oanda.com/convert/fxhistory?date_fmt=us'
fx_url_end = '&lang=en&margin_fixed=0&format=CSV&redirected=1'
cur1,cur2 = 'USD','AUD'
fx_url = fx_url + date_f + date_s + '&exch=' + cur1 +'&exch2=' + cur1
fx_url = fx_url +'&expr=' + cur2 +  '&expr2=' + cur2 + fx_url_end
data = urllib.urlopen(fx_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
data = str(soup.findAll('pre', limit=1))
data = replace(data,'[<pre>','')
data = replace(data,'</pre>]','')
file_location = '/Users/location_edit_this'
file_name = file_location + 'usd_aus.csv'
file = open(file_name,"w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

---

edit: to get values from a table:
example from: [palewire](http://www.palewire.com/tag/python-beautifulsoup-table-parse/)

```
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()

url = "http://www.palewire.com/scrape/albums/2007.html"
page = mech.open(url)

html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find("table", border=1)

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    rank = col[0].string
    artist = col[1].string
    album = col[2].string
    cover_link = col[3].img['src']

    record = (rank, artist, album, cover_link)
    print "|".join(record)
```

Comment: Is there a easy way to parse html tables into csv using beautiful soup?  Your example seems to focus on text enclosed in 'pre' tags.

Comment: with beautiful soup you just look for any tag you like that is near the data you want then findAll('thattag',limit=x) ...

Comment: Also, just look at the docs for Beautiful soup, there is many options to accomplish a variety of tasks.

Comment: Nice! I tried to generalize your solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611418/scrape-html-tables

Answer (score 11):

This is my python version using the (currently) latest version of BeautifulSoup which can be obtained using, e.g.,

```
$ sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

The script reads HTML from the standard input, and outputs the text found in all tables in proper CSV format.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import csv

def cell_text(cell):
    return " ".join(cell.stripped_strings)

soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read())
output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        col = map(cell_text, row.find_all(re.compile('t[dh]')))
        output.writerow(col)
    output.writerow([])
```

Comment: Works! Since I'm working with unicode characters, changed `import csv` to `import unicodecsv as csv` following this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31642070/4355695 . Have to install unicodecsv : `pip2 install unicodecsv`

Answer (score 5):

Even easier (because it saves it for you for next time) ...

In Excel

Data/Import External Data/New Web Query

will take you to a url prompt. Enter your url, and it will delimit available tables on the page to import. Voila.

Comment: any links how to improve the data? I get multiple excel rows for one html-row ( one TD has comments, alt-text etc. this becomes mult. rows in excel)

Answer (score 5):

Two ways come to mind (especially for those of us that don't have Excel):

- Google Spreadsheets has [an excellent `importHTML` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342):

  - `=importHTML("http://example.com/page/with/table", "table", index`
  - Index starts at 1
  - I recommend a `copy` and `paste values` shortly after import
  - File -> Download as -> CSV
- Python's superb [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library has handy [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.io.html.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas.io.html.read_html) and [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) functions

  - Here's [a basic Python3 script](https://gist.github.com/n8henrie/08a31f02fd1282d12b75) that prompts for the URL, which table at that URL, and a filename for the CSV.

Comment: This is an excellent tip, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

Copy out of browser into Excel, save as CSV.

Better solution (for long term use):

Write a bit of code in the language of your choice that will pull the html contents down, and scrape out the bits that you want.  You could probably throw in all of the data operations (sorting, averaging, etc) on top of the data retrieval.  That way, you just have to run your code and you get the actual report that you want.

It all depends on how often you will be performing this particular task.

Answer (score 2):

Excel can open a http page.

Eg:

1. Click File, Open
2. Under filename, paste the URL  ie: [How can I scrape an HTML table to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259091/how-can-i-scrape-an-html-table-to-csv)
3. Click ok

Excel does its best to convert the html to a table.

Its not the most elegant solution, but does work!

Answer (score 2):

Basic Python implementation using BeautifulSoup, also considering both rowspan and colspan:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def table2csv(html_txt):
   csvs = []
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_txt)
   tables = soup.findAll('table')

   for table in tables:
       csv = ''
       rows = table.findAll('tr')
       row_spans = []
       do_ident = False

       for tr in rows:
           cols = tr.findAll(['th','td'])

           for cell in cols:
               colspan = int(cell.get('colspan',1))
               rowspan = int(cell.get('rowspan',1))

               if do_ident:
                   do_ident = False
                   csv += ','*(len(row_spans))

               if rowspan > 1: row_spans.append(rowspan)

               csv += '"{text}"'.format(text=cell.text) + ','*(colspan)

           if row_spans:
               for i in xrange(len(row_spans)-1,-1,-1):
                   row_spans[i] -= 1
                   if row_spans[i] < 1: row_spans.pop()

           do_ident = True if row_spans else False

           csv += '\n'

       csvs.append(csv)
       #print csv

   return '\n\n'.join(csvs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **tested** example that combines grequest and soup to download large quantities of pages from a structured website:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
import csv
import grequests
import time

def cell_text(cell):
    return " ".join(cell.stripped_strings)

def parse_table(body_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body_html)
    for table in soup.find_all('table'):
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            col = map(cell_text, row.find_all(re.compile('t[dh]')))
            print(col)

def process_a_page(response, *args, **kwargs): 
    parse_table(response.content)

def download_a_chunk(k):
    chunk_size = 10 #number of html pages
    x = "http://www.blahblah....com/inclusiones.php?p="
    x2 = "&name=..."
    URLS = [x+str(i)+x2 for i in range(k*chunk_size, k*(chunk_size+1)) ]
    reqs = [grequests.get(url, hooks={'response': process_a_page}) for url in URLS]
    resp = grequests.map(reqs, size=10)

# download slowly so the server does not block you
for k in range(0,500):
    print("downloading chunk ",str(k))
    download_a_chunk(k)
    time.sleep(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it with excel?
If you save a spreadsheet in excel as html you'll see the format excel uses.
From a web app I wrote I spit out this html format so the user can export to excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're screen scraping and the table you're trying to convert has a given ID, you could always do a regex parse of the html along with some scripting to generate a CSV.