# Using the HTTP Accept Header from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

- I have a web service that performs a database search.  It accepts both GET and POST requests, and can return data in either JSON, CSV, or HTML format based on the HTTP `Accept` header.
- I have a web page that makes an Ajax request to this web service, and displays the search results.
- I have been asked to add a button to this page that will allow the user to save the data in CSV format.

Earlier this year, someone was [in the same boat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515162/need-to-save-html-table-to-csv-using-javascript), and got the response

> You cannot do it using javascript
>   capabilities, since javascript has no
>   permission to write on client machine,
>   instead you can send request to server
>   to create csv file and send it back to
>   client.

So I added a button that does

`window.open("MyWebService.cgi?" + theSameQueryStringIPassedInTheAjaxCall)`,

which opens the HTML version in a new browser tab.  I want the CSV version.  Is there a way I could pass an `Accept: text/csv` HTTP header?  (I know how to do it with XMLHttpRequest and setRequestHeader, but that doesn't help me.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a parameter to the querystring? (e.g. format=csv)

Comment: I'd prefer not to reimplement something that's part of the HTTP protocol.  But I could easily do that if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so. I think you should use an parameter instead.