# How to download a file on click of a button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie on JS and want to be able to download .csv files at the click of a button.
Currently I have a table showing a delete and a download button. I am not sure how to create a downloadable link with the file path for when clicking on the download button.

Table

```
"<button style='padding: 6px !important;' data-id = " + item.ID + " class='delete'><img src='/uas_tools/crop_analysis/Resources/Images/delete.png'></button>" +
"<button style='padding: 6.6px !important;' data-id = " + item.ID + " class='download'><img src='/uas_tools/crop_analysis/Resources/Images/download.png'></button>" +
```

Function

```
// onclick of download button
$(document).on("click", ".download", function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id'); //get id
        var selector = $(this);
        //window.location = _OBJECT_URL;

        console.log("CLICKED");
        console.log("id " + id);
})
```

Comment: Why not just make a hyperlink (instead of a button) which has the URL of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download html table as csv along with images src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555283/how-to-download-html-table-as-csv-along-with-images-src)

Answer (score 8):

Recommend using the download attribute for download instead of  Javascript or jQuery:

```
<a href="your_link" download> file_name </a>
```

This will download your file, without opening it.

But if you want by javascript example :
HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="yourlink">Download</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.yourlink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('mysite.com/file1'); // it will open download of filepath

});
```