# Scrape HTML tables from a given URL into CSV

Tags: html, language-agnostic, parsing, csv, screen-scraping

I seek a tool that can be run on the command line like so:

```
tablescrape 'http://someURL.foo.com' [n]
```

If `n` is not specified and there's more than one HTML table on the page, it should summarize them (header row, total number of rows) in a numbered list.
If `n` is specified or if there's only one table, it should parse the table and spit it to stdout as CSV or TSV.

Potential additional features:

- To be really fancy you could parse a table within a table, but for my purposes -- fetching data from wikipedia pages and the like -- that's overkill.
- An option to asciify any unicode.
- An option to apply an arbitrary regex substitution for fixing weirdnesses in the parsed table.

What would you use to cobble something like this together? 
The Perl module [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.10/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) might be a good place to start and can even handle the case of nested tables.
This might also be a pretty short Python script with [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup).
Would [YQL](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2009/02/data-scraping-with-yql-and-jquery/) be a good starting point?
Or, ideally, have you written something similar and have a pointer to it?
(I'm surely not the first person to need this.)

Related questions:

- [How can I scrape an HTML table to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259091/how-can-i-scrape-an-html-table-to-csv)
- [How can I convert an HTML table to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403087/how-can-i-convert-an-html-table-to-csv)
- [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: Sorry @dreeves, but Stack Overflow isn't a "free programmers for hire" service.

Comment: But where's the **Question**?

Comment: Edit the question if you would like to reformulate it.

Comment: (done; thanks. note that i ask this in case a tool like this exists. and in case not, i'm writing it myself and will share it here)

Comment: If you already have [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) installed (both useful tools in their own right), then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403087/how-can-i-convert-an-html-table-to-csv/72418856#72418856) for a one-liner that will very likely what you're looking for. If you want that _exact_ syntax, wrap in some shell script that passes the first argument to an `:nth-of-type()` CSS selector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my first attempt:

http://yootles.com/outbox/tablescrape.py

It needs a bit more work, like better asciifying, but it's usable.  For example, if you point it at this [list of Olympic records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics):

```
./tablescrape http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics
```

it tells you that there are 8 tables available and it's clear that the 2nd and 3rd ones (men's and women's records) are the ones you want:

```
1: [  1 cols,   1 rows] Contents 1 Men's rec
2: [  7 cols,  25 rows] Event | Record | Name | Nation | Games | Date | Ref
3: [  7 cols,  24 rows] Event | Record | Name | Nation | Games | Date | Ref
[...]
```

Then if you run it again, asking for the 2nd table,

```
./tablescrape http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics 2
```

You get a reasonable plaintext data table:

```
100 metres | 9.69 | Usain Bolt | Jamaica (JAM) | 2008 Beijing | August 16, 2008 | [ 8 ]
200 metres | 19.30 | Usain Bolt | Jamaica (JAM) | 2008 Beijing | August 20, 2008 | [ 8 ]
400 metres | 43.49 | Michael Johnson | United States (USA) | 1996 Atlanta | July 29, 1996 | [ 9 ]
800 metres | 1:42.58 | VebjÃ¸rn Rodal | Norway (NOR) | 1996 Atlanta | July 31, 1996 | [ 10 ]
1,500 metres | 3:32.07 | Noah Ngeny | Kenya (KEN) | 2000 Sydney | September 29, 2000 | [ 11 ]
5,000 metres | 12:57.82 | Kenenisa Bekele | Ethiopia (ETH) | 2008 Beijing | August 23, 2008 | [ 12 ]
10,000 metres | 27:01.17 | Kenenisa Bekele | Ethiopia (ETH) | 2008 Beijing | August 17, 2008 | [ 13 ]
Marathon | 2:06:32 | Samuel Wanjiru | Kenya (KEN) | 2008 Beijing | August 24, 2008 | [ 14 ]
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) I produced a rough script. Given the complexity of web tables it'll likely need to be tailored on all sites.

This first script lists the tables on the page:

```
# A simple table scraping example. It lists the tables on a page
#
# Cmds.Site = the URL to scan
default %Cmds.Site% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics
GotoURL %Cmds.Site%

set %Count% 1
foreach %Table% in (response //table)
    Notice Table #%Count%
    # find a suitable name, look back for a header
    set %Check% ./preceding::*[name()='h1' or name()='h2' or name()='h3'][1]
    if checkIn %Table% %Check%
        Notice (selectIn %Table% %Check%)
    end

    set %Count% as binOp %Count% + 1
end
```

The second script then extracts the data of one table into a CSV file.

```
# Generic extract of contents of a table in a webpage
# Use list_tables to get the list of table and indexes
#
# Cmds.Site = the URL to scan
# Cmds.Index = Table index to scan
default %Cmds.Site% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics
default %Cmds.Index% 2

GotoURL %Cmds.Site%

set %Headers% //table[%Cmds.Index%]/tbody/tr[1]
set %Rows% //table[%Cmds.Index%]/tbody/tr[position()>1]

# Get an cleanup the header fields 
set %Fields% withvector
end
foreach %Header% in (response %Headers%/*)
    putin %Fields% (trim %Header%)
end
Notice %Fields%

# Create an output CSV
call unit.file.CreateDataFile with
    %Name% %This:Dir%/extract_table.csv
    %Format% csv
    %Fields% %Fields%
end
set %DataFile% %Return:Value%

# Now extract each row
foreach %Row% in (response %Rows%)
    set %Record% withvector
    end
    foreach %Cell% in (selectIn %Row% ./td)
        putin %Record% (trim %Cell%)
    end

    call unit.file.WriteDataFile with
        %DataFile% %DataFile%
        %Record% %Record%
    end
end

call unit.file.CloseDataFile with
    %DataFile% %DataFile%
end
```

My CSV file looks like below. Note that wikipedia has extract information in each cell. There are many ways to get rid of it, but not in a generic fashion.

```
Shot put,22.47 m,"Timmermann, UlfUlf Timmermann",East Germany (GDR),1988 1988 Seoul,"01988-09-23 September 23, 1988",[25]
Discus throw,69.89 m,"Alekna, VirgilijusVirgilijus Alekna",Lithuania (LTU),2004 2004 Athens,"02004-08-23 August 23, 2004",[26]
Hammer throw,84.80 m,"Litvinov, SergeySergey Litvinov",Soviet Union (URS),1988 1988 Seoul,"01988-09-26 September 26, 1988",[27]
Javelin throw,90.57 m,"Thorkildsen, AndreasAndreas Thorkildsen",Norway (NOR),2008 2008 Beijing,"02008-08-23 August 23, 2008",[28]
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks nice. In the version I wrote I ended up putting in special cases to remove what you're calling wikipedia's extract information.

Comment: RIP TestPlan, I guess. The last Wayback Machine capture is from [2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825202616/http://testplan.brainbrain.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Using [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), and a tip of the hat to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403087/how-can-i-convert-an-html-table-to-csv/72418856#72418856):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# tablescrape - convert nth HTML table on a page to CSV or tab-delimited
# author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/785213
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77031218
set -u

input=${1:?"Expected a file, URL, or '-' as the first argument."}
nth=${2:-1}
mode=${3:-csv}

(
    if [[ -r $input || $input == - ]]; then
        cat "$input"
    else
        # '--location' means "follow redirects"
        curl --silent --show-error --location "$input"
    fi
) \
  | pup "table.wikitable:nth-of-type($nth) tr json{}" \
  | jq --raw-output '.[]
      | [
          .children[]                            # all .children of <tr>s
            | select(.tag=="td" or .tag=="th")   # that are <td>s or <th>s
            | [ .. | .text? ]                    # recurse, looking for .text
            | map(select(.))                     # filter out empty nodes
            | join(" ")                          # concatenate .texts together
        ]                                        # all <td>s/<th>s as an array
      | @'$mode                                  # join together as CSV or TSV
```

Both `jq` and `pup` are super-useful on their own. It *seemed* like one of those tools <s>(or else [xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html))</s> should be able to extract HTML tables directly to a delimited text file, but I guess it isn't so. Fortunately, [pipes, man](https://youtu.be/ZQnyApKysg4?t=831). They're so good!

### Usage

```bash
RECORDS='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics'

# read from a URL
./tablescrape $RECORDS 2

# read from a pipe or redirection
curl -sS $RECORDS | ./tablescrape - 1 tsv

curl -sS $RECORDS > records.html
< records.html ./tablescrape - 1 tsv

# read from a file
./tablescrape records.html 1 tsv
```

---

**Update**: Turns out [Xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) (0.9.8) *can* do it. Compliant CSV would be tricky (escaping delimiters and quoting quotes, oh my), but tab-delimited is pretty straightforward, and could be converted by another tool like [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), or LibreOffice Calc. An advantage of the tab-delimited format is many other Unix text-processing tools already understand it (`cut -d $'\t'`, `sort -t $'\t'`, `awk -F '\t'`), and in a pinch, you can write a nearly-foolproof parser yourself, *e.g.*, in shell script.

```bash
# NB: uses Bash's "ANSI-C quoting" feature for a literal tab character
xidel -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_records_in_athletics \
  -e $'//table[2]//tr/string-join(td|th,"\t")' \
  | column -t -s$'\t'
```

Output:

```
Event                 Record      Athlete(s)                                                   Nation                Games                Date                Ref(s)
100 metres            10.61       Elaine Thompson Herah                                         Jamaica (JAM)        2020 Tokyo           July 31, 2021       [32]
200 metres            ♦21.34      Florence Griffith Joyner                                      United States (USA)  1988 Seoul           September 29, 1988  [33][34]
400 metres            48.25       Marie-José Pérec                                              France (FRA)         1996 Atlanta         July 29, 1996       [35]
⋮
3,000 m steeplechase  8:58.81     Gulnara Galkina-Samitova                                      Russia (RUS)         2008 Beijing         August 17, 2008     [41]
4×100 m relay         ♦40.82      Tianna MadisonAllyson FelixBianca KnightCarmelita Jeter       United States (USA)  2012 London          August 10, 2012     [42]
⋮
```

That smooshes the names together in the relay events, and there are some pesky leading spaces on the "Nation" column, but it gets you pretty close.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but maybe that's because my `column` is too old. This however can all be done with `xidel`; removing the no-break-spaces and excessive white-space, string-joining all items to create "|"-separated values and even white-space aligned columns. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Reino17/468f9ceed9822332c79e48e7f9eee274).

Comment: @Reino It's impressive to see what Xidel is capable of, and I struggle with it without good examples, so thanks for sharing that Gist. The fact remains, though, I'm going to _remember_ `column -t`, but not the Xidel syntax. `;)`

Comment: The `column -t -s$'\t'` is using a Bashism ([ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)), which _could_ be why you had trouble? It's just for better visual appearance in the answer anyway, and can be dropped in practice, or you can pipe into something else like `mlr --itsv --opprint --barred cat` or `xsv table`, if you happen to have those.