# How to Scrape Table Data (School Test Scores)?

Tags: html, csv, web-scraping, export-to-excel

What is an easy way to scrape tables from this [website](http://www.nclb.osse.dc.gov/)? (It's school test scores. It's public data). I need the 2011 data for each school. So, to start, I need, year: 2011, report type: report card, school group: DCPS Schools, School Level: Secondary Schools, School: (I then need the data for each school). My goal is to put the data in a mySQL database. If I can get the data into  CSV format or Excel, it will be easy to import.

I tried the technique outlined [here](http://blog.ouseful.info/2008/10/14/data-scraping-wikipedia-with-google-spreadsheets/), but I'm not having any luck. In Google Docs, I tried: `=ImportHtml("http://www.nclb.osse.dc.gov/dccas_reportcards.asp", "table", 1)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you automating it? Doing it by hand? What language do you want to use or are familiar with? There are hundreds if not thousands of ways of doing this… This question is too broad and vague.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403087/how-can-i-convert-an-html-table-to-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the message. You're right, my question was too broad.

I ended up using Google Docs' Spreadsheet and TableTools2, a Firefox add-on.