# How do I convert an HTML table to csv format?

Tags: html, csv, parsing

Is there an HTML parser or some library that automatically converts HTML tables into CSV data rows?

Comment: Storing an entire HTML page as CSV doesn't really make much sense. You mean convert an HTML table to CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/45274-html-table-csv.html) some perl script. And [online converter](http://www.cs.iupui.edu/~aharris/H2Text.html) (java needed). Or you can just manually copy HTML table from browser to OpenOffice Calc / MS Excel and save it as CSV - this [will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259091/how-can-i-scrape-an-html-table-to-csv) too.

[And here](http://davidvielmetter.com/?p=1357) you are step-by-step solution on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`sed s/'<td>'//g d1.txt | sed s/'<\/td>'//g | sed s/'<\/a>'/'<\/a>,'/g | sed s/'<\/em>'/'<\/em>,'/g  | sed s/'<tr>'/'<br>'/g | sed s/'<\/tr>'//g | sed s/'<th>'/'<b>'/g | sed s/'<\/th>'/'|                    <\/b>'/g> names1.html`

Comment: This could use some context.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this simple PHP script (also as online converter)
http://www.scherello.de/?id=243