# Generate csv download from multiple data sources in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, csv

I have a table displaying data from multiple sources, about half from a MySQL DB and half returned as a JSON object from an API. It's then formatted into a multi-dimensional array and passed into a CI view where the table is created from it (~10-200 rows generally).

CodeIgniter has nice options for just MySQL data, specifically dbtuil and the csv_from_result() function, but that's for SQL output only. Perhaps I can use some combination of the [Download Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html) CI class and the [jQuery plugin](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php) recommended in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161113/how-do-i-export-html-table-data-as-csv-file?rq=1)? The thread is about a year old, is that still the best solution for my case?

Comment: can you explain little bit more

Comment: Basically my CI controller pulls data from an API (via a CI library class I've built) and pulls data from a local DB (via a model), combines those two sources into a big array for display in a single table in the CI view. I'm just looking for a way to download all the data in that table to a csv

Answer (score 1):

This is a code snippet from php [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) add your column header to the top of your array

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```