# Need to export the data in jsp page to a CSV file

Tags: export-to-csv

I need to export a data in jsp page(i.e in a webpage) to a .CSV file onclick of a button.

Can someone help me on how to code?

Comment: See this previous question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159272/how-to-export-data-in-csv-format-using-java

Comment: Hi thanks. I want to do it from a client side .ie. just the data in the jsp to a csv file and not at the servlet level.                                 I have 2 jsp files. 1.Already has a table and i need to export that to a csv file 2.It just has one column and i need to export to csv file.

Comment: Can someone help me on this?I included the below code <%response.reset();
 response.setHeader("Content-type","application/csv");
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=test.csv"); %>                                                             This opens the excel sheet with all the jsp tags (entire code in jsp) and does not display the data in columns.

Comment: If I click on a button it should export to csv. i give this in the jsp page input type="button" name="export" value="Export to .CSV File" onclick="ExporttoCSV()"></input>                                  I have a function that does export to csv like this.                               <script>
 function ExporttoCSV()
  alert("I am clicked");
 response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","filename=\"test.csv\"");

</script>
 But this function is not being called when i click the button. Any thoughts on where I am going wrong.Pls help me.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do..That is at the server side.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836728/how-to-export-the-data-in-a-list-to-a-csv-file-in-the-server-side

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JDBC connectivity for this. Please refer to the below doc.
https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jdbccsv.shtml