# how to export the data in a list to a CSV file in the server side?

Tags: jsp, csv, export-to-csv

I have a list of Users and Non-users list which I am putting it in a jsp page by using a for loop and iterating thru html table  and . How do I export the data to CSV at the server side.
Exporting the data to CSV in the client side is complicated. 
I have very less knowledge wrt to J2EE. So please help me with this.If you can suggest me an approach, I can follow that..

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do this.

Req:On clicking a button in jsp it should export to CSV

jsp code

```
 <div>

  <input type="button" name="exporttocsv"  onclick="window.open('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GetUserDetails?exporttocsv=yes','toolbar=no','location=no','status=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=yes','resizable=yes','width=10','height=100');" value="Export to CSV"/>
</div>
```

GetUserDetails is my servlet.

Servlet side code.

```
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)                         throws ServletException, IOException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("here inside get method");

    String clickevent=request.getParameter("exporttocsv");


    if(clickevent!=null &&clickevent.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {

        System.out.println("IN here....... download csv file...");
       //Getting the list from a session and iterating through the list
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                List<User> nonusers =          (List<User>)session.getAttribute("nonUserList");

        response.setHeader("Content-type","application/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=test.csv");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("Device Name,Non-Users");
        for(User nonUser: nonusers)
        {
        out.println(nonUser.getDeviceName()+","+ nonUser.getCecId());
           }

        out.flush();  
        out.close();  


    }

Thanks for your help!!
```