# Change file name while generating CSV from Java project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In [How to export data in CSV format using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13159272/4284627), I found a solution to write the date to CSV files and the accepted answer works fine.

I need change file name to anything with .csv extention. Now I get WebServlet name as a file name without any extention.

Do you have any idea how to set a file name?

```
resp.setContentType("application/csv");
PrintWriter w = resp.getWriter();
w.println(generateCsvFile(policies));
w.flush();
w.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a file name to the header:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + filename + "'");
```

The browser will honor the header and use the file name for downloading file