# Save html table to a csv file

Tags: jquery, html-table, export-to-csv

I found the following post: [How do I export html table data as .csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161113/how-do-i-export-html-table-data-as-csv-file)

I've given the first example a try ("Option 1") and it's great... it pops up a window with all my data in CSV format,
but I need to give my users an option to actually save a physical file with the data... not just the pop up window.

I'm wondering how I can modify the code to also allow for saving of the file?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with that code if I were you, maybe try one of these libs? https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/ or http://papaparse.com/. Good luck.

Comment: @Yeysides i just tried the demos and it parses json to csv... and vise versa.. but it doesn't let you save to a file from what I can see

Comment: well once you get the file parsed you can do this and have the users download that file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: I apologize if this is not what you were trying to do