# JS download table to Excel with IE

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer

I need to download a table into Excel with IE browser. I have a solution with this codes. But it runs really slow, nearly half a minute to get the Excel done. Is there any other way to make this?

```
var curTbl = document.getElementById(tableid);
var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
var sel = document.body.createTextRange();
sel.moveToElementText(curTbl);
sel.select();
sel.execCommand("Copy");
oSheet.Paste();
oXL.Visible = true;
```

Comment: What tool do you use?  EXCEL VBA or JS?

Comment: Use Javascript to download

Comment: Why not something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161113/how-do-i-export-html-table-data-as-csv-file