# Exporting Pandas Dataframe as CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is a question concerning how to allow a user to export a Pandas dataframe to CSV format in Python 3.

For context, I have a Django `view` that accepts POST requests from jQuery, such that when a user clicks on a button on my website, it triggers a POST request to that Django `view` and performs some filtering to generate a Pandas dataframe. I want the users to be able to export the dataframe *on their end*, not into my personal local machine/project directory.

I make a sharp distinction between "downloading" and "exporting". Downloading can be easily done through the `pd.to_csv` method and basically saves the CSV file into a specified directory within *my local machine* (or my project folder, in fact). The problem is that the behavior I want is "exporting", which I define as when a user, upon clicking a button, is able to get the dataframe on *their* local machine.

The way I do "exporting" currently is by converting the Dataframe to an HTML `table` element, returning the HTML as the response of the POST request to jQuery, and use vanilla JS to inspect the `table` element to export the data on the user's end, following a protocol similar to [How do I export html table data as .csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161113/how-do-i-export-html-table-data-as-csv-file). The problem, however, is that when the dataframe grows too big, it becomes impossible to inspect the associated `table` element to generate a CSV file.

Any suggestion for exporting a Pandas dataframe to CSV is appreciated - it could be an original solution, in fact.

Comment: Your approach in the first section is correct. 
Once you get a **POST request**. use the ```pd.to_csv``` to convert it into a CSV file and save it in a directory in the server. Then you can create a method as per the answer in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file . And you can call the download() method, Thus now you can send the file as the response.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62013267/12889647 even this works. it is upto to you to choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your view function

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def get(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{filename}.csv"'.format(filename='myname')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    df = pd.DataFrame([{"name": "haha", "age": 18}, {"name": "haha", "age": 18}])
    writer.writerow([column for column in df.columns])
    writer.writerows(df.values.tolist())
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_csv(directory/file_name.csv')
```