# Problems by trying to convert HTML Table to CSV in MODx Revolution

Tags: php, html, csv, modx-revolution

I'm using following solution to convert HTML tables to CSV: [Converting HTML Table to a CSV automatically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498632/converting-html-table-to-a-csv-automatically-using-php) and it works fine when I use two files alone in my server.

Here you can see the adaptation of my code:

File 01: TABLE.PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $query_select = 'SELECT id, name, department, year FROM table WHERE year = 2000 ORDER BY name DESC';
    $query_result = mysqli_query($link, $query_select) or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

    $table = '
        <table id="result-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>NAME</td>
                    <td>DEPARTMENT</td>
                    <td>YEAR</td>
                    <td>Check</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)) {
        $table .= "
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    "<td>".$row['id']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['name']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['department']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['year']."</td>".
                    "<td><input type='checkbox' name=".$row['id']." value=".$row['id']."></td>".
                </tr>";
    }
    $table .= '
            </tbody>
        </table>';

    $_SESSION['table'] = $table;
    echo $table;
    echo '<a href=html2csv.php>Export to CSV</a>';
?>
```

File 02: HTML2CSV.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'simple_html_dom.php'; // Which is in http://www.example.com/simple_html.php as well.
$table = $_SESSION['table'];
$html = str_get_html($table);


header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
    $td = array();
    foreach($element->find('th') as $row) {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);

    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row) {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

As I said above these files together give me the result that I expect: a beautiful CSV file. (:
The problem occurs when I try to adapt it to MODx Revolution. I'm doing just like that:

In MODx Revolution I have a Resource called Result Table which has a snippet [[resultTable]] and a Link to the file html2csv.php. Here the source of the Resource:

```
<p>[[!resultTable]]</p>
<p><a href="http://example.com/html2csv.php">Export to CSV</a></p>
```

And here the snippet resultTable:

```
<?php
    $query_select = 'SELECT id, name, department, year FROM table WHERE year = 2000 ORDER BY name DESC';
    $query_result = mysqli_query($link, $query_select) or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

    $table = '
        <table id="result-table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>NAME</td>
                    <td>DEPARTMENT</td>
                    <td>YEAR</td>
                    <td>Check</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)) {
        $table .= "
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    "<td>".$row['id']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['name']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['department']."</td>".
                    "<td>".$row['year']."</td>".
                    "<td><input type='checkbox' name=".$row['id']." value=".$row['id']."></td>".
                </tr>";
    }
    $table .= '
            </tbody>
        </table>';

    $_SESSION['table'] = $table;
    return $table;
?>
```

The only essential modification is on the last lines where I didn't use echo, but return, just as advised by MODx Tutorial. Until here it works as well and I'm able to see the result table. When I click on the link that loads the file html2csv.php I am able to download a csv file, but unfortunately it has following error message:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in <b>/home/aloysia/www/html2csv.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

I've tried some workaround, but none has worked. So I hope that someone out there can help me once again and explain me what I'm doing wrong. (:

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably your `$_SESSION['table']` not being set. When modx runs, it initiates it's own session which you can't access automatically from outside. You could test it quickly by `var_dump($_SESSION)` in your html2csv.php. I'm not really sure about your solution overall, and why you don't generate the CSV directly from the database? But if you can't change the solution i would try including modx's index.php and setting `MODX_API_MODE = true` to access functions without loading a request. (assuming you're in the same web root somewhere!)

```
//In html2csv.php
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require_once('..path/to/index.php');

//You should now be able to access $_SESSION['table']
var_dump($_SESSION['table']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kristian! Unfortunately it didn't work. But I'm now following the suggestion to create the csv direct from the mysql select. I am quite close to the solution, but still getting some errors. Maybe you could help me to go further. Here the new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642362/csv-file-from-mysql-using-php-with-a-oop-aproach-mysqli-connect-etc