# How to save Fetched data from other website into CSV

Tags: php, html, csv

I am fetching data from my website using `Curl`. Data is fetched in `HTML Table` Format. So how to save the data in `CSV` format correctly

```
<?php
 $url = 'http://etea.edu.pk/result_controller';
 $ch = curl_init();
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 $params = [
   'search_res' => true,
   'search_value' => 108,
   'result_id'   => 272,
  ];
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 $file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");
 fputcsv($file,explode(',',$result));
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `explode` function for writing into csv file.

Comment: ok. that's fine. but the data is now in html format. so how to save only text in csv.? @Perumal93

Comment: You can use `strip_tags` to extract only the textual content out of HTML tags.

Comment: i have used, but it return some of the text with no space. so can't even explode.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498632/converting-html-table-to-a-csv-automatically-using-php

Comment: MarcM has commented out the link to the question already existing. You can refer to it to get it worked.

Comment: @AmirIqbal Yeah. It returns text with no space wrapped around them. Therefore, you may need to work around to get it or use third party library like the one mentioned in the link provided by MarcM.