# Encoding issues in python how to fix it

Tags: python, encoding, utf

I get this error while writing data to csv file

```
import csv
a = [u'eaTfxfwz', u'Edward', u'O\u2019Connell', u'ejoconnell@sbcglobal.net', u'Santa Clara', u'CA', 'UNITED STATES', u'150 Saratoga Avenue #306', u'', u'Santa Clara, CA', u'95051', u'', u'408-835-2209', u'None', u'', '', u'2012-010', u'pjOjJfwT', u'Undefined', u'Import', u'     ', ' San Jose HQ, CA ', '', '', u'Undefined', '', u'None', '', '', u'Undefined', u'Not Considered', '', u'']
f3 = open('test.csv', 'at')
writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow(a)
```

error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766955/how-to-write-utf-8-in-a-csv-file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `utf-8` encoding.

```
import csv
aenc=[]
a = [u'eaTfxfwz', u'Edward', u'O\u2019Connell', u'ejoconnell@sbcglobal.net', u'Santa Clara', u'CA', 'UNITED STATES', u'150 Saratoga Avenue #306', u'', u'Santa Clara, CA', u'95051', u'', u'408-835-2209', u'None', u'', '', u'2012-010', u'pjOjJfwT', u'Undefined', u'Import', u'     ', ' San Jose HQ, CA ', '', '', u'Undefined', '', u'None', '', '', u'Undefined', u'Not Considered', '', u'']
for x in a:
    aenc.append(x.encode('utf-8'))
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f3:
    writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(aenc)
```

Comment: does this worked for you did u tired it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```python
import csv
aenc = []

a = [u'eaTfxfwz', u'Edward', u'O\u2019Connell', u'ejoconnell@sbcglobal.net', u'Santa Clara', u'CA', 'UNITED STATES', u'150 Saratoga Avenue #306', u'', u'Santa Clara, CA', u'95051', u'', u'408-835-2209', u'None', u'', '', u'2012-010', u'pjOjJfwT', u'Undefined', u'Import', u'     ', ' San Jose HQ, CA ', '', '', u'Undefined', '', u'None', '', '', u'Undefined', u'Not Considered', '', u'']

for x in a:
    aenc.append(x.encode('utf-8'))

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f3:
    writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    writer.writerow(aenc)
```