# extract a column from a csv arabic file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, arabic

i m trying to extract a specific column from a arabic file to another file 
this is my code

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv
from os import open

file = open('jamid.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
test = csv.reader(file)
f = open('col.txt','w+', 'wb' ,encoding='utf-8')
for row in test:

    if len(row[0].split("\t"))>3 :
         f.write((row[0].split("\t"))[3].encode("utf-8"))

f.close()
```

and the file is like this :

```
4   جَوَارِيفُ  جواريف  جرف     اسم 
18  حَرْقى  حرقى    حرق     اسم
24  غَزَواتٌ    غزوات   غزو     اِسْمٌ
```

i keep gitting the same error :

```
File "col.py", line 5, in <module>  file = open('jamid.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: It looks like you want the standard `open` function, not the one in `os.open`. Its 3rd paramter is the file descriptor of the parent directory.

Comment: i have the same error using the standard open function

Comment: drop import of open and an 3etra  parameter ('wb')

Comment: i ve added the 3d parameter for this error TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Please take the habit of extracting a [mcve]. In this particular case, large parts of your code are not necessary, like e.g. the final `f.close()` and they should be eliminated before posting here.

Comment: thanks for being helpfull and kind to me as a beginner  @Ulrich Eckhardt

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - `f.close()` is needed in this case. There are some unnecessary lines but that is the bug - a misunderstanding about csv reader results in extra work. I don't see how this example could be any smaller.

Comment: I'm under the impression that everything that happens after the error line is irrelevant for a question here, because it isn't even executed, @tdelaney. Of course, for the real program they may be relevant but the reason to *demand* a MCVE is to put focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - I pasted the program and had a running copy in just a few moments. Technically, there were several problems in the code so I guess to you this should have been several questions. But it was all from trying to fix a basic problem. I don't see a problem with how this was posted.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: this is python3

Comment: The difference is like between giving people fish and teaching them how to fish. Isolating a problem and running it in a debugger are key skills every programmer needs to learn in order to be efficient, that's why I mentioned that the very approach to problem solving needs some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code. First, you are using the signature of the `open` function with `os.open`, but it has different paramters. You can stick with `open`. More importantly, you seem to be trying to fix the row coming out of `csv.reader` by splitting it again on tabs.

My guess is that you saw the entire line in `row[0]` so tried to fix it. But the problem is that that the reader splits on commas by default - you need to supply a different delimiter. Here its a bit problematic because your code splits with a tab but the example shows spaces. I used spaces in my solution, but you can switch that as needed.

Finally, you attempted to encode the strings before giving them to the output file object. That object should be opened with the right encoding and you should simply give it strings.

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv

with open('jamid.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as in_fp:
    with open('col.txt','w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as out_fp:
        csv.writer(out_fp).writerows(row[3] for row in
            csv.reader(in_fp, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
            if len(row) >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Pandas`. I am posting the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
# print(df.head(10))
my_col = df['اسم'] #Insert the column name you want to select.
print(my_col)
```

Ouput :
[image]
Note: I hope it takes Arabic encoding.

---

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",encoding='utf-8') 
saved_column = df['اسم'] #change it to str type
# f= open("col.txt","w+",encoding='utf-8') 
with open("col3.txt","w+",encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(saved_column)
```

Comment: i triyed pandas but it doesn't work, mybe it doesn't take arabic or at least my comande line doesn't take arabic caracteres

Comment: I tried in mine. It's working completely fine. However, if you could have posted error I may be some help.

Comment: i was using this code 
the same thing as you 
    # coding=utf-8
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("jamid.csv",sep="\r")
    saved_column = df["جذر"]
    f= open("col.txt","w+",encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(saved_column)
    f.close()

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using unicodecsv

[How to write UTF-8 in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766955/how-to-write-utf-8-in-a-csv-file)

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv
import unicodecsv as csv

file = open('jamid.csv', 'rb')
test = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
f = open('col.txt', 'wb')
for row in test:
    if len(row)>3 :
         f.write(row[3].encode('utf8'))

f.close()
```

Comment: one more thing is that the output is attached i triyed to add
    f.write('\n') in the if close but is seams that it s wrong thing to do

Comment: you can also learn how to use the with statement during file opening when working with file streams https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for

Comment: This has the same problem as the first: Since the reader defaults to comma delimiter, each row is read as one column and the hack is to split that with tabs. The real solution is to change the delimiter.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've updated my answer. Sorry for posting without giving it a second thought.