# csv.writer encoding 'utf-8', but reading encoding 'cp1252'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

When writing to a file I use the following code. Here it's upper case, but I've also seen the encoding in lower case `utf-8`.

```
path_to_file = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\jpm\Downloads', 'c19_Vaccine_Current.csv')

#write to file
with open(path_to_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile) 
    #write the headers of the csv file
    f.writerow(['County','AdminCount','AdminCountChange', 'RollAvg', 'AllocDoses', 'FullyVaccinated',                    'FullyVaccinatedChange', 'ReportDate', 'Pop', 'PctVaccinated', 'LHDInventory', 'CommInventory',
                'TotalInventory', 'InventoryDate'])
```

And to check if the *.csv is in fact `utf-8` I open it and read it:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as r:
    print(r)
```

I'm expecting the encoding to be `utf-8`, but I get:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\jpm\\Downloads\\c19_Vaccine_Current.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I pretty much borrowed the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766955/how-to-write-utf-8-in-a-csv-file/31642070#answer-37364412). And I've also read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-examples). It's crucial that I have the *.csv file as `utf-8`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding has to be specified on an open as well. The encoding in which a file is opened is platform dependant, it would seem to be cp1252 on windows.

You can check the default platform encoding with this: (on Mac it gives utf-8)

```py
>>>import locale
>>>locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
'UTF-8'
```

```py
with open('file', 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    ...
with open('file', 'w', encoding='utf-8'):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you credit for answering that. But I am still not sure how to save the *.csv with ```utf-8``` using ```csv.writer```. I started another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676553/unsure-if-csv-file-is-encoded-as-utf-8-using-csv-writer