# Python BeautifulSoup or CSV encoding issue with &nbsp

Tags: python, csv, unicode, beautifulsoup

I was looking for conversion of an HTML table to CSV format, and came across the following, which looked promising (as I am also trying to learn Python)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697784/838253

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my samples, and I encounter error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 753: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This seems to be the result of `BeautifulSoup` `stripped_strings` conversion of nonbreaking spaces `&nbsp;` into `u'\xa0'`
This looks like perfectly normal Unicode (although converting multiple `&nbsp;` into a single `u'\xa0' seems a bit off)

The error seems to come from the `csv` module.
Why can't this handle standard Unicode, and what is the best way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, the `csv` module doesn't support unicode, see the note at the beginning of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

You can use `UnicodeWriter` from the [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) to write csv data with Unicode.